# Unable to get Xdebug working within Vagrant & PHPStorm

Tags: debugging, vagrant, phpstorm, xdebug, remote-debugging

I have got my vagrant box setup with the following xdebug.ini file info

```
zend_extension=/usr/lib64/php/modules/xdebug.so
[XDEBUG]
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.remote_log = /log/xdebug.log
xdebug.scream=1
xdebug.cli_color=1
xdebug.show_local_vars=1

; var_dump display
xdebug.var_display_max_depth = 5
xdebug.var_display_max_children = 256
xdebug.var_display_max_data = 1024
```

The host name for my Vagrant is as follows:

```
192.168.33.10
```

So for instance the dev site I am working on looks as follows:
http://www.zabsite.com.192.168.33.10.xip.io

I've turned of my firewall in case this is doing something odd - but I cannot ever seem to get any connection. This was working fine on my old WAMP setup but am having no joy with my Vagrant box.

Can anyone help me out to get my PHPStorm IDE correctly setup? All I get is 'waiting for incoming connection with ide key 'PHPSTORM'

In PHPStorm I have setup my 'PHP Remote Debug' as follows:

Host: www.zabsite.com.192.168.33.10.xip.io
Port: 80
Debugger: Xdebug

I have also set up the absolute path on the server to the public html directory.

Comment: Enable xdebug logging and see what it will say. Does it even tries to connect? maybe it tries to connect to a wrong IP:port?

Comment: I have created a new file within my vagrant box
/vagrant/log/xdebug.log & added the following line to my xdebug.ini
xdebug.remote_log=/log/xdebug.log

Would this appear to be correct what I am doing? (sorry i'm a bit of noob with vagrant)

I cannot see anything in the log file I created once i restart nginx..but thats more than likely me configuring this wrong

Comment: I'm not good with vagrant either. In any case:it should be full path to xdebug log. 1) Is this `/log/xdebug.log` is the FULL path 2) Access rights? (anyone should be able to write to it) 3) If log is empty then it could also mean that xdebug does not see debug request flag (cookie or GET/POST parameter) -- which means that you could be doing something wrong. In any case: try `xdebug.remote_autostart = 1` to tell xdebug to debug **every single request**. Alternatively try placing `xdebug_break();` in your PHP code (programmatic breakpoint)

Comment: Articles/manuals: 1) http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Zero-configuration+Web+Application+Debugging+with+Xdebug+and+PhpStorm 2) http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2013/07/webinar-recording-debugging-php-with-phpstorm/

Comment: cheers will try that out